Paper suggesting breaking RSA may be easier than factoring
A paper When $e$-th Roots Become Easier Than Factoring
by Antoine Joux, David Naccache, and Emmanuel Thomé is on eprint. I saw a mention of it on social media. It seems clear that this is a significant paper.
Abstract

We show that computing
$e$-th roots modulo $n$
is easier than
factoring
with currently known methods, given subexponential
access to an oracle outputting the roots of numbers of the form

$$x_i+c.$$

Here $c$ is fixed and $x_i$ denotes small integers of the
attacker's choosing.


Several variants of the attack are presented, with varying
assumptions on the oracle, and goals ranging from selective to
universal forgeries. The computational complexity of the attack in most significant
situations matches the special number field sieve's complexity.

It seems to me while both main attacks are less expensive than GNFS, the main result which justifies the claim "easier than factoring" is the following.

This sheds additional light on rsa’s malleability in general and on rsa’s
resistance to affine forgeries in particular – a problem known to be polynomial for $x_i >\sqrt{3} n$, but for which no algorithm faster than factoring
was known before this work [i.e., for arbitrarily small $x_i$ is my take on this].

QUESTIONS:
How serious a threat are these results in practice? Of course extracting $e$-th roots is the same as breaking plain RSA. But in general the paper doesn't beat SNFS for this problem. However, the authors state on page 2 that

Our experimental results for N = 512 and a recent snfs-factoring record clearly underline the insecurity of affine-padding rsa.


Is affine padding RSA common? I am ignorant and there are people here who would know, I'm sure.
After the affine padding is broken then we're left with plain RSA, but for that no attack faster than SNFS seems to exist, at least to me. Is this statement correct?


Not an answer, but remarks: 1) if the difficulty of a breaking some RSA scheme was made that of SNFS factoring for equivalent modulus size, that would be quite significant, because the best currently known attacks have the difficulty of GNFS for that modulus size, which is much higher. 2) a big question is whether the attack can be applied/extended (in a chosen-messages context) to RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5

This paper was published in 2007...

Not sure that this is true, but the attack would only work for certain conditions of $e$ while e.g. using F4 (or other larger primes) would make this attack unlikely or impossible? That would exclude a lot of implementations.

I thought the proof for "RSA is as hard as factoring" was simply that a black box cracking RSA could be used to factor large integers. So factoring is at most as hard as RSA. Of course it is possible that factoring is easier than believed,
